# file in use while reading from a txt file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

When a new user creates an account on my site I create some empty text files for him using io.file. For his future use. When account is created the user is logged in. On his home page I try to read text in page load event. But it always gives the error that file is in use. When I close the browser and then try to read the text from that file. It reads without any problems.

Comment: Did you close the file after creating it?

Comment: Where is the question or any specific details?

Comment: Post the sequence of events - when do you create the file, when do you try to read it again. And as Dan said - are you sure to close it asap after using it? What happens if two separate pages (two requests) try to access the file at the same time?

Comment: How to close the file? After creating it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you open a file, you have to make sure to close it.

```
    Dim file As IO.FileStream

    file = IO.File.OpenWrite("filename")

    ' ...

    file.Close()
```

Or by using

```
    Using file As IO.FileStream = IO.File.OpenWrite("filename")
        ' ...
    End Using
```

There's also functions that open and close the file right away.

```
    IO.File.WriteAllText("filename", "content")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx)?

> ```
> FileStream File.Create(string path)
> ```
>
> The FileStream object created by this method has a default FileShare value of None; no other process or code can access the created file until the original file handle is closed.

So wrap it in a `using` block.